# Какой командой на c# узнать состояние PPPOE подключения? подключено или нет

Tags: c#, сеть

Какой командой на c# узнать состояние PPPOE подключения? подключено или нет

Comment: как вариант ipconfig вызывать из cmd

Comment: NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable ?

Comment: Родной поддержки ras в C# нет, попробуйте взять готовую обертку, например dotRas - https://github.com/mogikanin/DotRas